# How to convert a list of lists into a multi-level nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to convert a list of lists to multi-level nested dictionaries like so:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 4, 5],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]


print(f(x))
## {
##  1: {2: {3: 4,
##          4: 5}
##      },
##  5: {6: {7: 8}}    
## }
```

The list inside can be arbitrary long. Any ideas would be very helpful. For any set of nested keys, there is only one unique value possible. Thank you. So, the list mentioned below does not occur:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4],
     [1,2,3,5]]
```

I tried the function below but it throws an AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'.

Also, it updates incorrectly as mentioned below, so not very helpful.

```
def listoflists_dict(listformat):
    a = dict()
    cur = a
    for inner_list in listformat:
        for i, ele in enumerate(inner_list):
            print(a)
            if (ele not in cur.keys()) and (i < len(inner_list) - 1):
                cur[ele] = dict()
                cur = cur[ele]
            elif (ele not in cur.keys()) and (i == len(inner_list) - 1):
                cur[ele] = inner_list[-1]
            else:
                cur = cur[ele]
    
    return a

listformat = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [1, 2, 4, 5],
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]

listoflists_dict(listformat)

## {}
## {1: {}}
## {1: {2: {}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4, 1: {}}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4, 1: {2: {}}}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4, 1: {2: {4: {}}}}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4, 1: {2: {4: {5: 5}}}}}}}
## {1: {2: {3: {4: 4, 1: {2: {4: {5: 5}}}}}}}
```

Comment: What do you do with `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]`?  `{1:{2:{3:4}}}`, then "update" value 4 to key 4, and add the 5? or maybe `{1:{2:{3:[4,5]}}}`?

Comment: The inner lists are unique. It doesn't matter. @MarkTolonen

Comment: _"but it throws an error"_: what error?

Comment: Your first codeblock commented out "result" isn't a valid dictionary.  What would be the *valid* result of `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]`?

Comment: The case mentioned by you is not possible for my data. There is only one unique value for any set of nested keys. In my example, I have mentioned ```[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,5]]```, ```[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,5]]``` I have updated my question as per your concern

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, I have updated the error. Although my logic itself is wrong, so I am not sure mentioning the error helps in any way.

Comment: `{2: {3: 4}, {4: 5}}` isn't a valid dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea, with two major problems:

- You don't reset `cur` for each `ele`. Moving `cur = a` one line down will fix this problem.
- The element that needs special handling is `len(inner_list) - 2`, not `len(inner_list) - 1`. You must not process `len(inner_list) - 1`, so a `break` is useful.

With this, your code becomes:

```
def listoflists_dict(listformat):
    a = dict()
    for inner_list in listformat:
        cur = a
        for i, ele in enumerate(inner_list):
            if (ele not in cur.keys()) and (i < len(inner_list) - 2):
                cur[ele] = dict()
                cur = cur[ele]
            elif (ele not in cur.keys()) and (i == len(inner_list) - 2):
                cur[ele] = inner_list[-1]
                break
            else:
                cur = cur[ele]
    
    return a
```

Now, several non-essential comments:

- `ele not in cur.keys()` will sequentially test each key in `cur`, since `cur.keys()` is a generator; `ele not in cur` will directly test if a key is present in a dict, and should therefore be preferred
- Similarly, `{}`, as a literal is faster than `dict()`, which must invoke a function
- It is easier to tear off the last two elements, rather than having to check for them

With that, here is a faster and sleeker version:

```
def listoflists_dict(listformat):
    a = {}
    for *path, key, val in listformat:
        cur = a
        for ele in path:
            if ele not in cur:
                cur[ele] = {}
            cur = cur[ele]
        cur[key] = val
    return a
```

Comment: Thank you, @Amadan. This worked perfectly. This was my first question on stack overflow. :)

Comment: "Sleeker" to write `cur = cur.setdefault(ele, {})` instead of `if ele not in cur: cur[ele] = {} cur = cur[ele]`.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, for a second I started to do so, but.... I wanted to address the `in cur.keys()` antipattern, and write out in Python what `dict.setdefault` does behind the scenes anyway.